# AppleScript How to copy file to system path

Tags: macos, applescript

I write an AppleScript

> do shell script "mv /Users/xxx/Documents/1.png /usr/local/"
> with administrator privileges

But it failed and return "Operation not permitted".

I know that Apple don't allow copy file to /usr/local. But if I change the destination folder from "/usr/local/" to "/Users/xxx/Desktop/", the script also failed.

In addition,  script like these all succeed. ↓↓↓

> do shell script "touch /usr/local/1.txt" with administrator privileges

or

> do shell script "mkdir /usr/local/testfolder" with administrator privileges

Why create file or folder finally succeed but copy file failed?

Comment: "Apple don't allow copy file to /usr/local"  You aren't allowed to access any location at your will.

Comment: RE: "Apple don't allow copy file to /usr/local" --  That statement is not true! I have no problem copying/moving _files_ to `/usr/local/` when done properly and all appropriate permissions have been authorized depending on how the copying/moving is being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of **macOS**, not sure how far back, if you want to copy/move *files/folders* from within the default *folders* of your **Home** *folder* to e.g. `/usr/local` using the `do shell script` *command* in e.g. **Script Editor**, then it needs to be first copied/moved to a *folder* that is not within the default *folders* of your **Home** *folder*.

In other words, if the *files/folders* are in the *root* of your **Home** *folder*, the **Public** *folder*, or a **user** created *folder* within your  **Home** *folder*, then that's not a problem. However, if it's in **Desktop**, **Documents**, **Downloads**, **Library**, **Movies**, **Music**, **Photos**, or **Pictures**, then the *files/folders* will need to first be copied/moved elsewhere and then to `/usr/local`.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me:

```
do shell script "mv ~/Documents/1.png ~/Public/"
do shell script "mv ~/Public/1.png /usr/local/" with administrator privileges
```

**Notes:**

In *scripts* where I've needed to do this I first copy/move the *files/folders* to `/private/tmp/` as I'm sure I will not accidentally overwrite something elsewhere in my **Home** *folder*.

That said, while I can certainly see reasons for wanting to use a `do shell script` *command* over **Finder**, nonetheless, **Finder** is a viable option as mentioned in the other answer.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The two cases shown ("/usr/local/" and the desktop) are protected differently on new system and have different explanations for their behavior.

1. **desktop**. To move a file using the **"mv"** command to the desktop, you just need to grant to this command access to the desktop (or full disk access). Because it is a non-system location, albeit with some protection.
2. **"/usr/local/" folder**. This is a **SIP protected system folder**. Therefore, only granting access to it will not help here. It is usually advised to temporarily disable SIP with two computer reboots, and so on.

I personally find this advice to be bad. Better to abandon the "mv" command and let the system itself move what is only allowed to it.

```
set thePNG to (choose file of type "png") as text
set usrLocalFolder to ((path to (startup disk)) as text) & "usr:local"

tell application "Finder" to move file thePNG to folder usrLocalFolder
-- tell application "Finder" to move file thePNG to desktop
```

Comment: When there is an opportunity to get information in a convenient form, I do not try to get the same thing in a complicated form in order to seem to someone smarter than I am (Terminal, ls, drwxr-xr-x and so on). Simply viewing information about a given folder using the Get Info menu gives the following information on my Mac. **System: read & write, Whell: read only, Everyone: read only**. Nothing is coded and everything is clear. The folder is systemic and protected. For the admin account, nothing at all. And you can't even add it

Comment: I am not sure now how it is protected, by it is read only for everyone except the System. I shown the solution to move file to this protected folder. With one thing I am sure - if some folder is SIP protected (/usr), then every its files and subfolders is SIP protected (/usr/local for example)